# Excel Convert Date to 18-Digit AD TimeStamp

Tags: excel, timestamp

Excel formula to convert date (10/15/2019) to 18-Digit AD Timestamp for Eastern Time.

I can find examples of how to go from 18 Digit to Date but not date to 18-digit.

Basically, want to convert an entire column of dates in column E from 10/5/2019 , 10/15/2019, 11/18/2019,etc...to values like 132157440000000000

These are accountExpires AD attributes which I've heard need to be long Int, but also referred to as 18-digit AD Timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a 18-Digit AD TimeStamp:

```
=((A1-A2)*86400000+11644473600000)*10000
```

Where:
A1 is your date, like 10/5/2019.
A2 is the date 1/1/1970.
86400000 is number of milliseconds on 1 day.
11644473600000 is number of milliseconds between 1/1/1601 and 1/1/1970.
10000 to make it 18 digit.

Answer (score 0):

Using this formula above will get you 154858343846970000 - a date in the year 2091.
I noticed that the milliseconds derived above (11644473600000) is between 1/1/1601 and 1/1/1970.  Excel bases the date's "serial number" based on the number of days until 1900, not 1970.  (1970 is for unix epoch).  If you change it to 9435483102000 (the number of m'secs between 1/1/1900 and 1/1/1601) you get the timestamp for 10/5/2019 (132147055020000000) in GMT TZ.
So...
([Excel Date Serial Number from difference]*86400000+9435483102000)*10000 works
HTH